# Retrieve Card Info from Charge in Stripe

Tags: grails, stripe-payments

I am triggering a charge using:

```
charge = Charge.create(chargeParams)
```

In the chargeParams I am passing the card ID associated with stripe but in the charge object the card object is null. How do I fetch card info. from a charge in stripe. I also tried Charge.retrieve(id) but it also returned null for card.

Comment: Can you post your `chargeParams` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create charge with stored card as:

```
token = params[:stripeToken]

# create a Customer
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  card: token,
  description: 'description for payinguser@example.com',
  email: 'payinguser@example.com'
)

# charge the Customer instead of the card
Stripe::Charge.create(
    amount: 1000, # in cents
    currency: 'usd',
    customer: customer.id
)
```

For further [reference](https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-save-a-card-and-charge-it-later)

Comment: I know how to use stored card.(By passing the card ID). But I want to fetch card. info. from the charge object.I found an alternative way. I can use Token.retrieve(id) and then use token.card.